# C# Moving a selected mail item to inbox subfolder

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

can anyone provide an example of how to move a selected inbox item to a inbox subfolder hitting a wall with the moveitem function.

Thanks

Comment: Select a mailItem within your source folder. Then use the "move" method of the selected "mailItem" object.

Answer (score 2):

```
MAPIFolder inbox = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GeteEfaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
MAPIFulder subfolder = inbox.Folders["Subfolder Name"];
MailItem mail = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection[1];
mail.Move(subfolder);
```